# How to get proper data from a WooCommerce product CRUD webhook?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a system that is able to receive webhooks from many WooCommerce sites.

I've also created a bunch of WooCommerce instances and configured them to webhook this address https://requestb.in/qivtf4qi whenever a product CRUD action occurs.

However, when performing a CRUD action over a product in one of the WooCommerce instance, the webhook content seem incorrect:

- It doesn't contain any payload,
- It doesn't contain any way to identify where the webhook came from (Instance domain etc), except the originating server IP (Quite unreliable if the instance is moved or scalled horizontally).

What is the correct way to have WooCommerce deliver *proper* webhook data?

[See an example of what gets sent on product update: no way to identify the instance, no content so quite pointless as we would have to query all the products to find out which one was updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riNiq.png)

[See how each WooCommerce instance is configured to deliver hooks to that single service we're building.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsBZD.png)

[See how the WooCommerce API docs say that the webhook payload should actually carry the resource like if it was modified using the REST API. They also mention a header, `X-WC-Webhook-Source`, that should contain the source domain.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kOcv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that two things are needed (Unknown from WooCommerce docs) for the webhooks to be delivered:

- The CURL PHP extension has to be installed and enabled.
- The webhooks get delivered by Wordpress cron job (`wp-cron.php`), and in our development environment it wasn't set up.

As suggested in [this issue](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/15599), inspecting the per-webhook log helps as well, as an empty log suggest a problem in the setup like described earlier (CURL / Cron etc).